# one line edits to files in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sed

I have many very large files (> 6 GB) stored in an AWS S3 bucket that need very minor edits done to them.

I can edit these files by pulling them to a server, using `sed` or `perl` to edit the key word, and then pushing them back, but this is very time-consuming, especially for a one-word edit to a 6 or 7 GB text file.

I use a program that makes the AWS S3 like a random-access file system, https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse, but this is unusuably slow, so it isn't an option.

How can I edit these files, or use `sed`, via a script without the expensive and slow step of pulling from and pushing back to S3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

The library you use certainly does it right: download the existing file, do the edit locally, then push back the results. It's always going to be *slow*.

With `sed`, it may be possible to make it faster, assuming your existing library does it in three separate steps. But you can't send the result right back and overwrite the file before you're done reading it (at least I would suggest not doing so.)

If this is a one time process, then the slowness should not be an issue. If that's something you are likely to perform all the time, then I'd suggest you use a different type of storage. This one may not be appropriate for your app.